# Your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, uwsgi, supervisord

I run a flask app on uwsgi. I use supervisor to manage uwsgi process. I find the log saying that

> your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections.

How to overcome 100 connections limitation?
My running script is as below:

```
[program:myapp]
command=uwsgi --master -s /tmp/app.sock --module myapp:app --processes 2 -H /srv/sites/mysite chmod-socket 666 --enable-threads
```

Comment: Are you sure that is what you need to do? If you accumulate a backlog of 100 connections, you must be using at least about 99% of your capacity, and then increasing the limit will only give you an extremely minimal breathing space before the number of incoming connections exceed what you can possibly serve. It would be much more productive to figure out how you can serve the requests faster.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Note that a "listen backlog" of 100 connections doesn't mean that your server can only handle 100 simultaneous (or total) connections - this is instead dependent on the number of configured processes or threads. The listen backlog is a socket setting telling the kernel how to limit the number of outstanding (as yet unaccapted) connections in the listen queue of a listening socket. If the number of pending connections exceeds the specified size, new ones are automatically rejected. A functioning server regularly servicing its connections should not require a large backlog size.

According to the manual, you can change the listen backlog with the `-l` option:

```
-l|--listen <num>
       set  socket  listen queue to <n> (default 100, maximum is system
       dependent)
```

Answer (score 45):

Simply increasing the uwsgi's listen backlog using the `-l` or `--listen` option (as pointed by [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340047/uwsgi-your-server-socket-listen-backlog-is-limited-to-100-connections/12340078#12340078)) while starting the server, to a value greater than 128 might stop uwsgi from starting up. There is also a system level limit on Unix socket and TCP connection listen queue, whose default is 128, that needs to be increased.

You can verify that setting like this:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn
```

uwsgi has been [patched](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/pull/18) such that if the value passed to `--listen` parameter while starting uwsgi is greater than the system level limit, it'll cause uwsgi to fail hard. If you want set uwsgi's listen queue limit greater than the system level limit, you must first increase the kernel's limit.  That can be done executing the following commands:

```
$ echo 4096 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn
```

Or

```
$ sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=4096
```

Or, add `net.core.somaxconn=4096` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` for it to persist through a reboot.

Answer (score 10):

As it was described in previous answers:

1. Increase connections in kernel
2. Increase connections in uWSGI **too**

**Example**. If you are using **docker** and **docker-compose**.

1. How to increase connections in kernel

In `docker-compose.yml`, in block where you describe how to run uWSGI:

```
uwsgi_runner:
    <<: *app-base
    command: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /app/uwsgi.ini
    # ... other settings ...
    sysctls:
        net.core.somaxconn: 1024 # set max connections to 1024 in kernel
```

2. How to increase connections in uWSGI

In `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
# ... other settings ...
listen = 1024 # set max connections to 1024 in uWSGI
```

Also, you can change this parameter directly in **docker-compose command** (`-l` or `--listen` flag) if you are not using `uwsgi.ini` settings file:

```
uwsgi_runner:
    <<: *app-base
    command: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi -l 1024 #other-parameters-here
```

Comment: To have a perfect answer please describe how to Increase connections in kernel as you wrote.

Comment: Setting `net.core.somaxconn: 1024` is a step to increase connections in kernel, if your environment works in docker.

Comment: Hello Denis, edit your answer, don't answer in the comment form, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can modify SOMAXCONN in your `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` to increase this limit.

It's simply linux tuning systems.