# docker container increase listen queue size beyond 128

Tags: python, unix, docker, uwsgi

How can I increase the listen queue size beyond 128 on a docker image with a read only file system?

When I run my container I get the following error:

`uWSGI: - Listen queue size is greater than the system max net.core.somaxconn (128).`

I have a Dockerfile with base image [python:2.7](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).  I am trying to increase system level limit on Unix socket and TCP connection listen queue so that uwsgi can set a listen queue limit of 1024, as described at [uwsgi: your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340047/uwsgi-your-server-socket-listen-backlog-is-limited-to-100-connections).

I tried adding these `RUN` commands to the Dockerfile:

- `echo 4096 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`
- `sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=4096`

But these both fail with the following errors respectively:

- `/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: Read-only file system`
- `sysctl: setting key "net.core.somaxconn": Read-only file system`

I also tried mounting a file to overwrite the `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` and that failed with the error `cannot be mounted because it is located inside "/proc"`

I also tried running `sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=4096
net.core.somaxconn = 4096` on the host before running, but it isn't reflected in the docker container; uwsgi still fails with the error `uWSGI: - Listen queue size is greater than the system max net.core.somaxconn (128)` and running `cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` shows 128 in the container while showing 4096 on the host.

Comment: Should I try running with a different base image?

Comment: This is a question about system administration and not about programming and therefor off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You either need to run Docker in privileged mode than you can modify the `/proc` file system after the container was started or you upgrade to a newer Docker release. `run` subcommand has the [`--sysctl`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) option, which allows to make the change you envision:

`$ docker run -ti --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=4096 --rm ubuntu /bin/bash
root@9e850908ddb7:/# sysctl net.core.somaxconn
net.core.somaxconn = 4096`

Comment: can the container configuration be modified after the fact?  Or do I need to delete the container and create it again using the run command?

Comment: aws ecs containers ? does aws allow it from console parameters ?

Answer (score 14):

If you prefer using `docker-compose`. Here's the configuration that you want to adjust:

```
sysctls:
  net.core.somaxconn: 1024
```

Or

```
sysctls:
  - net.core.somaxconn=1024
```

Reference: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#sysctls